# Does a system metric or parameter exist for margins of icons on the desktop?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I find on Win7, when `Align Icons to Grid` is enabled, my desktop icons have a left margin of 13 and a top margin of 2.  Are there any system metric or parameters that report that?  Or even via `IFolderView2` or anything else?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you want [`SPI_GETICONMETRICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) because MSDN says that `SM_CXICONSPACING`/`SPI_ICONHORIZONTALSPACING` is the grid size.